# What is the white plastic cap on top of water heater for?

Tags: water-heater

I noticed that on the top of almost all gas water heaters, there is a plastic cap (mine has "caplugs bp-2" on it, which may just be the brand of the cap). What is it used for? Can I add an additional anode rod there?

Comment: Usually a brass nut screwed in there.

Comment: A picture may help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are sure your tank has only one rod and that rod is located someplace else, it probably already has your anode rod under it. If you have not checked/replaced the anode rod, you might have to dig into the insulation to find the head of the rod under it.

**If** you **are sure** your tank has only one rod and that rod is located someplace else, might just be the fill hole from applying the insulation foam between the tank and the jacket at the factory. Your water heater manual (generally available on the web if you have lost the paper copy) should show where the anode rod(s) is(are) located.

Comment: I've got one... it's a fill hole from adding the insulation.